# Is there a way to get newsletter of top questions of many websites all in one configuration?

Tags: feature-request

Each website has a newsletter section where you can subscribe, so that top questions of the month (or week I guess) would be sent to you.

This feature is so useful. But since the count of Q&A websites is rising rapidly, it's getting really frustrating to manage all subscriptions of the websites one is interested in.

For example, if somebody like to follow these fields:

1. Computer programming (StackOveflow, Programmers, CodeReview, etc.)
2. Music
3. Philosophy
4. English
5. French
6. Movies
7. etc.

he should go to 7 or more websites, subscribe to newsletter, and get 7 or more emails in mailbox's inbox.

Do we have this feature in StackExchange so that users can subscribe to multiple newsletters all in one configuration?